# Почему ассемблерной код для ссылки и указателя одинаковый?

Tags: c++, указатели, ссылки

**C++:**

```
    void f(int *ptr)
    {
       *ptr;
    }

    void f(int &ptr)
    {
       ptr;
    }
```

**ASM:**

```
f(int*):
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rdi
        nop
        pop     rbp
        ret
f(int&):
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rdi
        nop
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

Почему ассемблерной код для ссылки и указателя одинаковый?

Comment: А почему бы ему не быть одинаковым? Откуда возник такой вопрос?

Comment: @AnT, имеют разные свойства. Например: ссылка не занимает места в памяти. Хотя в переданную функцию будет(наверное) занимать столько сколько и указатель.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Потому что суть ссылки, особенно в таком простом случае - та же, что и у указателя. *Грубо говоря*, ссылка - это указатель, который постоянно разыменовывает сам компилятор за вас.

Comment: и указывает только на один и тот же обьект...

Comment: @Harry, это понятно, а как тогда работает механизм ссылок когда она по сути псевдоним объекта(если это "указатель")?

Comment: Да так и работает - с неявным разыменованием. Компилятор отрабатывает соответствующим образом. Теоретически, может быть, возможны и другие варианты работы ссылок - не как неявных указателей... но такой - пожалуй, проще всего. Или я неверно понял ваш вопрос? тогда уточните, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 5):

И ссылка и указатель  - обеспечиваю програмисту доступ к обьекту используя адрес в памяти. Поэтому при одинаковых попытках обратится к обьекту или его полям - приведут к генерации одинакового кода.

1.Например `void f(int *ptr){*ptr;}` равнозначно   `void f(int &ptr){ptr;}`

2.`void f(int *ptr){ptr;}` равнозначно   `void f(int &ptr){&ptr;}`

3.`void f(obj*p){p->toStr();}`равнозначно`void f(obj& p){p.toStr();}`

Запись разная - а значение - одинаковое. Есть правда некоторые особенности, но они не влияют на то какой код сгенерируется - если суть одинакова - сгенерируется одинаковый код:

- Указатель может быть пустым - ссылка не может быть пустой.
- при использовании `new` `delete` `this`  более удобны переменные с использованием указателя (по ссылке можно - но гораздо сложнее выражения).
- через указатель, можно использовать обьект, как массив (`void f(int *ptr){ptr[0];}`),  через ссылку нет.
- доступ к полям при указателе происходит посредством `->`, а к полям ссылки через точку `.`.
- от указателя можно перейти к ссылке используя унарный оператор `*` и от ссылки можно перейти к указателю используя унарный оператор `&`. (не унарные опрераторы выполняют математические или логические действия).

Comment: через указатель, можно использовать обьект, как массив ... Не согласен с этим  выражением.